# Can we have $\sf V=HTD$? How it relates to $\sf V=HOD$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, type-theory, axioms, definability

In my search for some [type-set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4122497/reference-request-is-axiom-of-choice-motivated-along-type-set-lines?) motivated line of thought that might prove axiom of choice, I was thinking of a concept that looks like $\sf V=HOD$, but in terms of types instead of ordinals, that is we think *informally* along the following lines:

$X \text{ is type definable } \iff \\ \exists \alpha_1,.., \exists \alpha_n \exists \phi : \forall y (y \in X \iff \phi(y,\alpha_1,..,\alpha_n))$

However, this is known not to be done in first order logic since it involves quantification over all formulas. So, I'll resort to the alterantive approach, which I'll write, paralleling comments by Hamkins, as:

**Type-Definability:** $\forall X \, \exists \theta \, \exists \alpha < \theta \, \exists \varphi :  X=\{y \in V_\theta\mid V_\theta\models\varphi(y,\alpha)\}$

Where $V_\theta$ is the set of all sets of type $< \theta$

Note: all term symbols in Greek denote *types* as explained in the linked posting on type-set theory.

We'd label that by "type-definable" even though this term had been used in other contexts.

I'd label the above axiom as: $\sf V=HTD$.

That is, all sets are Hereditarily Type-Definable.

> Is this formalisable in the language of [Type-Set Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4122497/reference-request-is-axiom-of-choice-motivated-along-type-set-lines?)?

> Would adding it to axioms of [Type-Set Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4122497/reference-request-is-axiom-of-choice-motivated-along-type-set-lines?) prove Axiom of Choice?

> How this would relate to $\sf V=HOD$? Would adding it over the aformentioned Type-Set theory have the same consequences as adding $\sf V=HOD$ over $\sf ZF$?

Comment: "Type-definable" has a standard (and totally different) meaning in model theory, so I would recommend choosing different terminology.

Comment: @Alex Kruckman, hmmm..., but this is so legitamate here that it's very hard to deviate from? It is at the heart of the matter! One needs to be cautious not to confuse both, the contexts are different.

Comment: Your definition seems to use a truth predicate. This is not how we define HOD. It is a motivating idea, but that idea (because it uses a truth predicate) is not formalizable in ZFC. Rather, the definition of HOD employs reflection and the definability of the $V_\alpha$ sets.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, yes but this alterantive can be done, because we have reflection here, and also we have something similar to the $V_\alpha$ sets which are the type sets. So, I think HOD can be paralled in types (not sure though).

Comment: OK, so why not make the definition that way then? Otherwise, one needs an account of your use of a truth predicate.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, because I'm not experienced in this technical side of presenting ordinal definability. However, it appears to me that it could be done, anyhow I'll try read about his and try come up with the specific alternative that works. I was thinking naively of just replacing the ordinals with types in those definitions.

Comment: In ZFC, the statement V=HOD can be expressed by saying: for every set x, there is an ordinal $\theta$ and an ordinal $\alpha<\theta$ and a formula $\varphi$ such that $x$ is the unique object in $V_\theta$ for which $V_\theta\models\varphi(x,\alpha)$. This does not use a truth predicate in $V$, but only in $V_\theta$, which we can prove exists in ZFC. The proof that this agrees with the external idea of definable in $V$ with ordinal parameters, however, is quite subtle.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, thanks for the clarification, I'll write this in the posting in terms of types.

Comment: You could alternatively (equivalently) say:  V=HOD iff for every $x$ there is $\theta$ and $\alpha<\theta$ and $\varphi$ such that $x=\{a\in V_\theta\mid V_\theta\models\varphi(a,\alpha)\}$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, yes! That is nearer to the intention behind this method.